# How is this variable still NULL

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm in the process of writing a CasperJS script to automate a search form and capture the subsequent page.  However, the search form goes to a loading splash page first until data arrives.  So i added the `waitForSelector` function which seems to be working for some of my pages, but others return the variable `name` as `NULL`.  How can that be if it is truly "waiting" for that element to be on the DOM?

```
casper.each(searchPages,function(casper,index){
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 2;
    var day = currentTime.getDate();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    var dateStart = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    month = currentTime.getMonth() + 3;
    var dateEnd = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

    casper.thenOpen(url,function(){
        var myfile = "data-"+year + "-" + month + "-" + day+".html";
        this.evaluate(function(j) {
            document.querySelector('select[name="searchParameters.localeId"]').selectedIndex = j;
        },index);
        this.evaluate(function(start) {
            $("#leaveDate").val(start);
        },dateStart);
        this.evaluate(function(end) {
            $("#returnDate").val(end);
        },dateEnd);
        this.evaluate(function() {
            $("#OSB_btn").click();
        });

        this.waitForSelector('#destinationForPackage', function() {
            var name = casper.evaluate(function() {
                return $("#destinationForPackage option[value='" + $("#destinationForPackage").val() + "']").text()
            });
            if (name != "Going To"){
                if (name == null){
                    console.log("it's null");
                }else{
                    name = name.replace("/","_");
                    casper.capture('Captures/Searches/search_' + name + '.jpg');
                    console.log("Capturing search_" + name);
                }
            }
        },function(){
            console.log("Search page timed-out.");  
        },20000);
    });
});
```

Comment: 'How can that be if it is truly "waiting" for that element to be on the DOM?' You're not waiting for *that* element. You're waiting for `#destinationForPackage`, but `name` isn't that element; it's the result of `$('#destinationForPackage option...').text()`.

Comment: @JordanRunning Ok, but `#destinationForPackage` is a select box element, and to my understanding, the corresponding function and code will not be executed until `#destinationForPackage` is on the DOM.  No?

Comment: @JordanRunning Do you know how to fix this to work with what i'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a recursive function if the element is still not available.  Now i'm having a memory issue though, new question here => [CasperJS running out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348193/casperjs-running-out-of-memory)

```
casper.each(searchPages,function(casper,index){
    loadSearch(casper,index);
});


function loadSearch(casper,index){
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 2;
    var day = currentTime.getDate();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    var dateStart = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    month = currentTime.getMonth() + 3;
    var dateEnd = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

    casper.thenOpen(url,function(){
        var myfile = "data-"+year + "-" + month + "-" + day+".html";
        this.evaluate(function(j) {
            document.querySelector('select[name="searchParameters.localeId"]').selectedIndex = j;
        },index);
        this.evaluate(function(start) {
            $("#leaveDate").val(start);
        },dateStart);
        this.evaluate(function(end) {
            $("#returnDate").val(end);
        },dateEnd);
        this.evaluate(function() {
            $("#OSB_btn").click();
        });

        this.waitForSelector('#destinationForPackage', function() {
            if (this.exists('#destinationForPackage')){
                var name = casper.evaluate(function() {
                    return $("#destinationForPackage option[value='" + $("#destinationForPackage").val() + "']").text()
                });
                if (name != "Going To"){
                    if (name == null){
                        console.log("it's null");
                    }else{
                        name = name.replace("/","_");
                        casper.capture('Captures/Searches/search_' + name + '.jpg');
                        console.log("Capturing search_" + name);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                console.log("Still doesn't exist...retry");
                loadSearch(casper,index);
            }

        },function(){
            console.log("Search page timed-out.");  
        },20000);
    });
}
```