# CasperJS running out of memory

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I'm running the following script with CasperJS and after about 1/3rd of the way through the array it starts running out of swap space and the machine becomes extremely slow.  What am i doing wrong here?

`searchPages` is an array of 54 numbers corresponding to a URL value for a search page.

```
casper.each(searchPages,function(casper,index){
    loadSearch(casper,index);
});


function loadSearch(casper,index){
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 2;
    var day = currentTime.getDate();
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    var dateStart = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    month = currentTime.getMonth() + 3;
    var dateEnd = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

    casper.thenOpen(url,function(){
        var myfile = "data-"+year + "-" + month + "-" + day+".html";
        this.evaluate(function(j) {
            document.querySelector('select[name="searchParameters.localeId"]').selectedIndex = j;
        },index);
        this.evaluate(function(start) {
            $("#leaveDate").val(start);
        },dateStart);
        this.evaluate(function(end) {
            $("#returnDate").val(end);
        },dateEnd);
        this.evaluate(function() {
            $("#OSB_btn").click();
        });

        this.waitForSelector('#destinationForPackage', function() {
            if (this.exists('#destinationForPackage')){
                var name = casper.evaluate(function() {
                    return $("#destinationForPackage option[value='" + $("#destinationForPackage").val() + "']").text()
                });
                if (name != "Going To"){
                    if (name == null){
                        console.log("it's null");
                    }else{
                        name = name.replace("/","_");
                        casper.capture('Captures/Searches/search_' + name + '.jpg');
                        console.log("Capturing search_" + name);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                console.log("Still doesn't exist...retry");
                loadSearch(casper,index);
            }

        },function(){
            console.log("Search page timed-out.");  
        },20000);
    });
}
```

And it adds about 3GB per loop.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well turns out this is a very well-known issue with PhantomJS.  3+ years as an open bug and apparently it has something to do with QT Webkit.  Nonetheless, i was able to solve it by closing each page during the loop and re-opening a new Phantom page.  It's a bit of a hacky work-around, but the memory consumption is far less.  However, after about 200 pages, it still has a pretty high memory usage (1GB+).  So, i break up my scripts into blocks of 200 and just start the next one upon completion.   Here is the finished product that completes successfully without too much memory usage.  It uses less on MacOS than Windows for some reason.

```
casper.start(url,function(){
    this.echo('continuing captures...');
}).each(searchPages,function(casper,index){
    loadSearch(this,index);
});

function loadSearch(casper,index){
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = currentTime.getDate() + 1;
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
    var dateStart = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    var fortnightAway = new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);
    var dateEnd = fortnightAway.getMonth() + 1 + "/" + fortnightAway.getDate() + "/" + fortnightAway.getFullYear();

    casper.page.close();
    casper.page = require('webpage').create();

    casper.thenOpen(url,function(){
        var myfile = "data-"+year + "-" + month + "-" + day+".html";
        this.evaluate(function(j) {
            document.querySelector('select[name="searchParameters.localeId"]').selectedIndex = j;
        },index);
        this.evaluate(function(start) {
            $("#leaveDate").val(start);
        },dateStart);
        this.evaluate(function(end) {
            $("#returnDate").val(end);
        },dateEnd);
        this.evaluate(function() {
            $("#OSB_btn").click();
        });
        this.waitForSelector('#destinationForPackage', function() {
            if (this.exists('#destinationForPackage')){
                var name = casper.evaluate(function() {
                    return $("#destinationForPackage option[value='" + $("#destinationForPackage").val() + "']").text()
                });
                if (name != "Going To"){
                    if (name == null){
                        console.log("it's null");
                    }else{
                        name = name.replace("/","_");
                        name = name.replace("/","_");
                        casper.capture('Captures/Searches/search_' + name + '.jpg');
                        console.log("Capturing search_" + name);
                    }
                }
            }else{
                console.log("Search failed to load. Retrying");
                loadSearch(casper,index);
            }

        },function(){
            console.log("Search page timed-out. Retrying");
            loadSearch(casper,index);
        },20000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better solution to the original issue, but for a quick fix on running out of memory, try `setTimeout` to make the recursive call without winding up the stack...

```
setTimeout(() => loadSearch(casper,index), 0);
```

(This idea assumes that the memory issue is the result of too much recursive depth over a long wait time).

Comment: Doesn't that just call the function immediately since the timeout parameter is set to 0?  I've never seen setTimeout used like that.

Comment: And by original issue do you mean my other post? If so id love to hear it.

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup, it calls it without delay, but without delay on the next turn of the run loop, giving the current invocation a chance to pop off the stack.  Re: the original issue, I wish I knew enough to be more helpful there.

Comment: I'm running the script now (it takes 15-20 minutes before i see if there's a memory leak).  I did, howerever, have to write the setTimeout function like this.  `setTimeout(function(){loadSearch(casper,index)}, 0);`

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup, yeah, that's the <ES6 style.  I should have mentioned.

Comment: Still did not resolve the issue.  I've updated the post with a capture of the memory it's using.  It's HUGE!

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup, sorry to hear.  At least this rules out blowing the stack   as the source of memory loss.